# Best package for scraping HTML with Python from site that needs cookies enabled

Tags: python, web, web-crawler, urllib2

I am currently using Python 3.6 to crawl a file of URLs and search for a certain string. After running the script, the HTML returned indicated that cookies needed to be enabled. Mechanize and every other library I find is not supported for any versions of python 3.x. Can someone point me in the right direction of libraries that can enable cookies so the correct HTML is rendered?

Comment: `requests` module is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can both retrieve and send cookies with the awesome `requests` package.

**Sending cookies:**

```
cookies = {
    cookies_are:'working'
    }

requests.get(url, cookies=cookies)
```

**Retrieving cookies:**

```
r = requests.get(url)
r.cookies #return a dictionary
```

More information check out the [requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v1.0.0/user/quickstart/). Hope it helps!